# php - Can't delete input in table using sql statement

Tags: php, sql-delete

I don't know what I have done to this but I had the form working and now it has stopped. My problems are with the bottom if statement where I am trying to delete the user. As I said it was working properly and now it has stopped. I just can't figure out what the issue is? And yes I do backup but clearly should do it more!

```
function HMdisplayrooms() {
    global $wpdb;
    echo '<html><body><h1>Display Rooms</h1>';
    echo '<p>Order room view by: <p>
    <form name = "view_HM_rooms" method="post" action="">
            <select name="roomsView" size = "1">
                <option value = "room_id">Room ID</option>
                <option value = "room_type">Room Type</option>
            </select></br>
            <input type="submit" name="action">
    </form></body></html>';
    echo '<table border="1" style="width:1000px" cellspacing ="0"><tr><td><b>Room      ID</b></td><td><b>Room Type</b></td><td><b>Options</b></td></tr>';
    if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
        $roomType = $_POST['roomsView'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM hm_room ORDER BY $roomType ASC";
        $rooms = $wpdb->get_results($query);

        foreach ($rooms as $room) {
            $roomID = ($room->room_id);
            echo '<tr><td>'.format_to_post($room->room_id).'</td><td>'.format_to_post($room->room_type).'</td><td><form name = "HotelManiaRoomDeletion" method="post" action="">
            <input type="submit" name="action2" value="Delete Room"></form></td></tr>';

            if(isset($_POST['action2'])){
                $results = $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM hm_room WHERE room_id='".$roomID."'");
                $msg = "Room deleted";  
                return $msg;
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: You have your form and delete query set inside a `foreach` loop. You sure you want to do that?

Comment: can you post the error or warning msg. If any thing is coming.

Comment: I don't know php and am not a very good coder, only just started. I was simply making a table using php and it needed a form by it. I just want to delete the room that has the associated delete submit button. It was working, but I don't know how I broke it.

Comment: when you click `Delete Room` `$_POST['action2']` will be set , but `$_POST['action']` will be null that time. Try checking that. @Fred-ii- you are right, the block should be made stand alone

Comment: No error message is coming up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the code like this,

```
function HMdisplayrooms() {
    global $wpdb;
    echo '<html><body><h1>Display Rooms</h1>';
    echo '<p>Order room view by: <p>
    <form name = "view_HM_rooms" method="post" action="">
            <select name="roomsView" size = "1">
                <option value = "room_id">Room ID</option>
                <option value = "room_type">Room Type</option>
            </select></br>
            <input type="submit" name="action">
    </form></body></html>';
    echo '<table border="1" style="width:1000px" cellspacing ="0"><tr><td><b>Room      ID</b></td><td><b>Room Type</b></td><td><b>Options</b></td></tr>';
    if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
        $roomType = $_POST['roomsView'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM hm_room ORDER BY $roomType ASC";
        $rooms = $wpdb->get_results($query);

        foreach ($rooms as $room) {
            $roomID = ($room->room_id);
            echo '<tr><td>'.format_to_post($room->room_id).'</td><td>'.format_to_post($room->room_type).'</td><td><form name = "HotelManiaRoomDeletion" method="post" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="DelRooMId" value="'.$roomID.'">
            <input type="submit" name="action2" value="Delete Room"></form></td></tr>';


        }       
    }

     if(isset($_POST['action2'])){
                $roomID = $_POST['DelRooMId']; // sanitize the input
                $results = $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM hm_room WHERE room_id='".$roomID."'");
                $msg = "Room deleted";  
                return $msg;
     }
}
```

I have pulled the `DELETE` block outside of your code. It may help you. The problem with your code is `$_POST['action']` will be null at the time of `DELETE` operation , so the code never executes, that may be the error

Note - Make sure to get the `$roomID` when you are using the below structure

Comment: I know what your saying but it was working so that is why I know I had it right.

Comment: Made some edits to the initial code, compare it with yours, may help you

Comment: OMG thank you. I don't know what I did before to make it work before, but this is much more elegant. I did not know about the hidden code.

Comment: I was glad to be able to help you. :-)